# aws ec2 lighsail nginx not pointing to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm very new to deploying on server. I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@idelara/step-by-step-guide-manually-deploying-a-laravel-app-running-on-lemp-to-an-aws-ec2-lightsail-d4792fd5c920) to deploy my laravel project from github and successfully completed all steps.

But when I point to my instance ip on browser, it loads nginx homepage rather than laravel.

check 1: `sudo nano /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

```
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = 127.0.0.1:8080
```

I suppose this means the instance should listen to laravel instead of any other?

What I suspect is, `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.site`
the myapp.site is empty. It suppose to create symlinks I suppose. How can I solve this issue?

This is what I see on browser for my instance ip:
[nginx welcome page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2AtS.png)

Comment: It says you need to copy the contents of https://gist.github.com/idelara/73182f098f6e6f3f1ad8169f2a1292b2#file-myapp-site into /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.site. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.site` should contain the value of [this file](https://gist.github.com/idelara/73182f098f6e6f3f1ad8169f2a1292b2#file-myapp-site) according to this tutorial.

Once it contains these contents perform the following actions:

- `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.site /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.site`
- `sudo service nginx restart`

Assuming the remaining parts of the tutorial are followed you should now be able to see your site.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216263/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-williams-aws-ec2-lighsail-nginx-not-pointing-to-la).